# m-tx fails: "bad argument #1 to 'write'"

Tags: musixtex

I am trying to typeset sheet music using `m-tx`. When I try to compile the example file `netsoos.mtx` from [the MusiXTeX website](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/htdocs/Introduction.html#SECTION00011000000000000000) I get the following output:

```
d:\folder>musixtex netsoos
This is musixtex.lua version 0.16e.
==> This is M-Tx 0.62 (Music from TeXt) <08 February 2016>
!! prepmx preprocessing of netsoos.mtx fails.
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\musixtex\musixtex.lua:564: bad argument #1 to 'write' (string expected, got nil)
```

I am rather sure that this is not a mistake in the source file, since it's the "official" example. The example file for `pmx` works fine.

What's wrong?

---

The contents of `musixtex.log` are

```
This is musixtex.lua version 0.16e.
Processing netsoos.mtx
  prepmx netsoos
!! prepmx preprocessing of netsoos.mtx fails.
```

Comment: What is in your `musixtex.log`?

Comment: @Marijn: I've added the log to my question. However, nothing new there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The binary in the MiKTeX distribution has been fixed. This issue should no longer appear.

---

There seems to be a faulty `prepmx.exe` in 64-bit MiKTeX. Downloading it directly [from ctan](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/m-tx/Windows64) and replacing `prepmx.exe` and `miktex-prepmx.exe` with that fixes the issue.

(Note however, that MiKTeX will want to "repair" these files when updating. You will have to take care that does not happen until the bug is fixed.)